# WHERE or HAVING for Date Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our SQL Server database has a string "2018001" for our fiscal periods and I convert that to a flattened date with:

```
CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(LEFT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 4), '-', RIGHT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 2), '-', '1'), 102) AS FP_DATE,
```

In order to aggregate sales by date and filter for dates `>= '2015-01-01'` is it better to use:

```
CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(LEFT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 4), '-', RIGHT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 2), '-', '1'), 102) >= '2015-01-01'
```

in the `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause?

e.g.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Net_Value),
    CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(LEFT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 4), '-', RIGHT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 2), '-', '1'), 102) AS FP_DATE
FROM
    DB123
WHERE  
    CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(LEFT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 4), '-', RIGHT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 2), '-', '1'), 102) >= '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(LEFT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 4), '-', RIGHT(FP_Based_on_Comm_Date, 2), '-', '1'), 102)
```

Comment: Don't store weird date formats and problem solved!

Comment: It's technically not a date, but a characteristic.

Comment: Not only weird date formats are bad but you can put that conversion in the app side (BL or sometimes in the UI) and persist a date and simplify your life a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can filter the conditions in the `where` clause, that is usually better.

Filtering before aggregation generally means that fewer rows are being aggregated -- and hence better performance.

On some (rather rare) occasions, filtering in the `where` clause can prevent the use of indexes or the generation of the best statistics and result in a *worse* query plan.  I believe that is rather rare.